# Why after using table() floating numbers are considered as integers?

Tags: r, types

I have a vector of float numbers of type `double` :

```
> typeof(globals$out$data$randrating)
[1] "double"
```

And after I turn it into a table, the same values return an `integer`:

```
> data_rating <- as.data.frame(table(globals$out$data$randrating))
> colnames(data_rating) <- c("rating", "freq")
> typeof(data_rating$rating)
[1] "integer"
```

To see what the data look like in data_rating :

```
> data_rating

   | rating | freq
1  |      4 |  312
2  |    7.1 |  324
3  |      8 |  340
4  |    8.5 |  962
5  |    8.7 | 1640
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the first column is `factor` and what we see by using `typeof` is the integer representation.  You can use `class` to find the actual `class`.

If we look at the `table` output, the `names` part is a `character` vector.  When we convert it to `data.frame` using `as.data.frame`, the `character` elements gets converted to `factor` as by default `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` for the `data.frame` call.  If we use `as.data.frame(...., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, it would change the `typeof`.

---

As a reproducible example,

```
 set.seed(24)
 v1 <- sample(c(1:20, 14.5, 18.2), 200, replace=TRUE)
 tbl <- table(v1)
 str(tbl)
 # 'table' int [1:22(1d)] 7 9 10 11 12 10 7 10 13 6 ...
 #- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
 # ..$ v1: chr [1:22] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...

 d1 <- as.data.frame(tbl)
 str(d1)
 # 'data.frame':   22 obs. of  2 variables:
 # $ v1  : Factor w/ 22 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ Freq: int  7 9 10 11 12 10 7 10 13 6 ...

 class(d1$v1)
 #[1] "factor"
 typeof(d1$v1)
 #[1] "integer"
 mode(d1$v1)
 #[1] "numeric"
```

Using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

```
 d2 <- as.data.frame(tbl, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 class(d2$v1)
 #[1] "character"
 typeof(d2$v1)
 #[1] "character"
 mode(d2$v1)
 #[1] "character"
```

The storage `mode` is `numeric` for the previous one and it is `character` for this.

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know thereafter how to check whether the data are of type integer or float ? I came across something like `typeof(as.numeric(as.character(data_rating$rating))` but it always returns `double` even if the data are all integers. I need to check whether the data in `data_rating$rating` are of type integer or float.

Comment: @YohanObadia  You can use `?class` i.e. `class(10.1)
#[1] "numeric"` and `class(10L)#
[1] "integer"`

Comment: `> class(as.numeric(as.character(data_rating$rating)))
[1] "numeric"` 
`> class(data_rating$rating)
[1] "factor"`
`> typeof(unclass(data_rating$rating))
[1] "integer"` but they are float...

Comment: If you have a tip that would be great :)

Comment: @YohanObadia  The storage mode of `factor` is `integer`.  FOr example `str(factor(1:3))
 Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3`  the `1 2 3` are the integer representation of the factor.  If we do on a non-numeric i.e. `str(factor(LETTERS[1:3]))#
 Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3`, you can find the `1 2 3` as the integer representation.

Comment: Ok I got it, thank you very much ! My solution to check wether the data are integer or float is `all.equal(as.numeric(levels(data_rating$rating)), as.integer(as.numeric(levels(data_rating$rating)))) == TRUE`

Comment: I did not find anything like it on stack, should I create a question and an answer ? I am relatively new to that website...

Comment: @YohanObadia  If you don't find anything on stack, you can create a question and answer it so that others benefit it.