# Check whether a factor variable is of type integer or float

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have a vector of numbers that can either be of type integer or double `globals$out$data$randrating`

After I turn it into a table, the same values return an integer as it is of class factor, whatever the values stored in data_rating$rating:

```
> data_rating <- as.data.frame(table(globals$out$data$randrating))
> colnames(data_rating) <- c("rating", "freq")

> class(data_rating$rating)
[1] "factor"

> typeof(data_rating$rating)
[1] "integer"
```

How can I check whether those data are of type integer or float ?

Here a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652012/why-after-using-table-floating-numbers-are-considered-as-integers/35652182#35652182) that led to this one.

**UPDATING THE QUESTION WITH REPRODUCIBLE DATA**

```
> data_rating

   | rating | freq
1  |      4 |  312
2  |    7.1 |  324
3  |      8 |  340
4  |    8.5 |  962
5  |    8.7 | 1640
```

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example of what actually the problem and what are you trying to achieve. Very unclear this Q/A it is...

Comment: So why don't you just use `is.double(globals$out$data$randrating)` and go with that?

Comment: It is a factor, so `is.double()` will be `FALSE`.

Comment: @Stibu I'm not talking about the table. I'm talking about the original vector, of which OP says that that vector is either integer or double.

Comment: I will clarify the question, however, I only created it in the purpose of sharing an information I learned through another question.
The purpose was not to check whether the data are of type factor. They are by a matter of fact. The purpose is to check whether data of type factor are actually double or integer...

Comment: `is.double(globals$out$data$randrating)` returns `TRUE` for both integer and float btw... `> y = 3   > is.double(y)   [1] TRUE`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the following code you can check whether the data are of type integer or not after being converted to a numeric format :

```
all.equal(as.numeric(levels(data_rating$rating)), 
          as.integer(as.numeric(levels(data_rating$rating)))) == TRUE
```

If that operation returns `TRUE` then it is an integer, if it returns `FALSE` it is a float.

Comment: When an anwser is downvoted, it would be respectful to explain why, in order at least for people to understand why...